# MySQL. What isolation level should be used?

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

There are many situations where I don't know what kind of isolation I should use in MySQL to avoid using corrupt data.

For example, let's say an application to make reservations for a theater. A user selects a seat and, within a transaction, it is checked that the selected seat is free and, if it is, the reservation is saved in a second step.

It may happen that while is verified that the seat is free and, before saving the reservation, another user reserve it first.

For situations like this and working with MySQL, what isolation level should I use?

Comment: Isolation level is too broad for this - you will probably need to use a mix of database and application level locks to handle concurrency issues. Database locks (which isolation levels can influence a bit) are just handled during the course of a database transaction, but a booking process is rarely covered by an open database transaction, particularly not in a web-based application.

Comment: Are you looking for *"Locking Reads If you query data and then insert or update related data within the same transaction, the regular SELECT statement does not give enough protection. Other transactions can update or delete the same rows you just queried. InnoDB supports two types of locking reads that offer extra safety: "*  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 3):

Shadow's right about the need for application level support for this kind of operation. In a web app in particular, each page view or AJAX request is a separate operation and may use its own connection, so you can't hold a transaction in an uncommitted state for multiple pageviews.

That being said, the default [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) isolation level should serve you well if your transactions do `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ; UPDATE ; COMMIT` sequences.

Comment: The problem that I wrote in the example is that I must check the table of reservations and, if there is none of the seat that I'm interested in, I can add it. I don't know if a select for update would work for me since the problem is that another user can add a new row. As far as I know, the select for update only locks the rows that select. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for how to check Isolation level your DB is using currently, you can use the following query.

*Note that Default Isolation level in MySQL is **REPEATABLE READ***

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'transaction_isolation';
```

[image: Example showing the use of same query]